# Getting exception while reading excel file with grails excel import plugin

Tags: java, grails, groovy, apache-poi

Exception : main] g.a.s.o.g.p.e.ExcelImportService         : Exception caught at row 1 column Employee Name while trying to set property name

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column index (-12811).  Allowable column range for BIFF8 is (0..255) or ('A'..'IV')

@Transactional
class FteDetailsFetchService {

```
   def excelImportService

   static Map CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP = [
           sheet:'data',
           startRow: 1,
           columnMap:  [
                   'Employee Name' : 'name'

           ]
   ]



   def fetchDataFromFTE(){
          InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\buildfax\\kapow\\BUILDFAX_RES_PMT.xls")
          Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp)
          def employeeList = excelImportService.columns(wb,CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP)
          println employeeList.size()
   }
```

}

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? Where did the problem excel file come from? If you open the file in Excel, does that give warnings?

Comment: i am using 3.16 version. I am not getting any warning.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?